# Mysql error in my syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey i have an error in my mysql syntax, and i dont know why i get it. I can't see an error in my code and i have checked the web for help...

```
    INSERT INTO downloads_log 
    (file,by,time) VALUES
    (1,1, NOW())
```

The error:

```
'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by, time) VALUES (1,1,NOW())
```

Comment: the syntax highlighter tells it all, `by` is a reserved word and you need to wrap that inside ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`by`,`file` and `time` are reserved keywords used in MYSQL. Use a back tick (`) to escape the keywords in your query. Change your query to :

```
INSERT INTO downloads_log 
    (`file`,`by`,`time`) VALUES
    (1,1, NOW())
```

Answer (score 2):

`by` is a reserved keyword. Try:

```
INSERT INTO downloads_log 
(`file`, `by`, `time`) VALUES
(1, 1, NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using reserved keywords as column names. Try to avoid using reserved keywords as column names, but if you haven't choice you have to pass them to backticks `` in following:

```
INSERT INTO downloads_log (`file`,`by`,`time`) VALUES (1,1, NOW())
```